# XCode Time Profiler does not record

Tags: xcode7.3

When building my XCode application for profiling and running the time profiler, it allows me to press record, but the recording immediately stops without any data. It seems that the correct application is selected in the time profiler, and I've used the tool several times before.

Any hints what I might be doing wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I identified the problem -- my application uses a multi-threaded third-party library, and XCode is for some strange reason not executing this part of the code...